# Django ORM replacement for extra where

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Here is a scenario that I currently plan solving with .extra(where=...) call:

```py
class CustomData(models.Model):
   data = models.CharField()
   target_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
   target_object_id = models.PositiveInteger()
   target_object = GenericForeignKey('target_type', 'target_object_id')

# list of tuples with object ID and mixed content type ID [(1, 15), (2, 15), (3, 11), (4, 12), ...]
related_objects = get_list_of_objects(...)
releated_custom_data = CustomData.objects.extra(
      where=['(target_object_id, target_type_id) = ANY (VALUES %s)'], 
      params=str(related_objects)[1:-1]
)
```

Based on the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#extra) extra is getting deprecated in the future. Is there a sensible alternative for making a value pair filtering with the ORM?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `Q` object that filters combinations of the two, like:

```
from django.db.models import Q

data = [(1, 15), (2, 15), (3, 11), (4, 12)]
q_filter = Q(
    *[Q(target_object_id=d1, target_type_id=d2) for d1, d2 in data],
    _connector=Q.OR
)

CustomData.objects.filter(q_filter)
```

Comment: Thanks. That would work, but this obviously looses the benefits of using the ANY in PostgreSQL, which gives far better query performance than a series of OR clauses. Any thoughts?